# Can a ii° built on ^2 of the harmonic minor scale with an added 6th function as a fully dimished 7 chord?

Tags: voice-leading

The added raised ^7 from using harmonic minor allows for a chord that is enharmonic to a fully dimished 7th
chord but built on ^2 not ^7. Can this chord be used as a fully diminished 7th chord?

Comment: That's the thing - ii°4/2 and vii°7 are enharmonically equivalent, so what is preventing me from interpreting your (however inverted) ii°7 chord as a (however inverted) vii°7 chord instead? (Hint: the harmonic function.)

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the question the wrong way round!   How DOES a dim7 chord function?  The main feature of a dim7 chord is that it can function in all sorts of ways. It's the ultimate multi-purpose pivot chord!  One contrived in the way you describe can lead the harmony off in many directions.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* a full diminished chord in its own right, so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Fully diminished seventh chords, because they are enharmonically equivalent, are often used interchangeably. That is to say, they are frequently used as pivot chords, spelled according to one key, but used dually.

The chord built on ^2 would be spelled ^2 ^4 ^b6 ^b8, and the chord built on ^7 would be spelled ^7 ^2 ^4 ^b6. The ^2 version would, by default be vii<sup>o7</sup>/iii and the ^7 version would be vii<sup>o7</sup>, but in a highly chromatic setting, they would essentially be equivalent, and the spelling would depend on usage and clarity.

Comment: Aaron, why would the chord built on 2 have a ^b8?, wouldn't it be a raised 7? Or would it be spelled as b8 because it is in the key of iii?

Comment: @armani One of the basic ideas in music theory is that chords are made up of thirds. A chord spelled with ^6 and ^7 would contain a second; a spelling with ^6 and ^1 would be a third. So ^b6 - ^b8 is a minor third; ^b6 - ^#7 is an augmented second, which would signal a chord inversion rather than root position.